# SwiftUi - plot data from Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, swiftui, graph, charts

I am reading a big csv file into a dataframe and do some modification on the data. Now I want to plot the data in Swift UI Charts, but I cannot find a effective way to get the x and y data direct from the dataframe without creating arrays from the columns I want to plot. Have any of you ever done this before?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [example] showing what you already have tried. See also [ask].